# Magento 2 Server side email validation

Tags: magento2, email, validation

I am trying to validate email in my custom controller file. Here is the code that i am trying...

```
if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim('test@r-u-i-.com'), 'EmailAddress')) {
    echo "not valid";
}else{
    echo "valid...";
}
```

This validation return me that this is a valid email address.
But when i am trying to create customer, Magento return me this error **"Email has a wrong format"**

Answer (score 4):

Ok finally i found the solution.

Actually M2 return "Email has a wrong format" this error from following file

```
magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Address
```

And in this method there is a email validation

```
public function validate(Address $address)
    {
        $warnings = [];
        foreach ($this->required as $code => $label) {
            if (!$address->hasData($code)) {
                $warnings[] = sprintf('%s is a required field', $label);
            }
        }
        if (!filter_var($address->getEmail(), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $warnings[] = 'Email has a wrong format';
        }
        if (!filter_var(in_array($address->getAddressType(), [Address::TYPE_BILLING, Address::TYPE_SHIPPING]))) {
            $warnings[] = 'Address type doesn\'t match required options';
        }
        return $warnings;
    }
```

So i simply used the code from this method.

```
if (!filter_var("test@r-u-i-.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
     $warnings[] = 'Email has a wrong format';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use Email Validator class:

```
\Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress
```

Usage example: [\Magento\CustomerGraphQl\Model\Resolver\IsEmailAvailable](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/CustomerGraphQl/Model/Resolver/IsEmailAvailable.php)

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Validator\EmailAddress $this->emailValidator */
if (!$this->emailValidator->isValid($args['email'])) {
    throw new GraphQlInputException(__('Email is invalid'));
}
```

Comment: A great solution - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To validate email in controller file you can use below code, hope this will help you.

```
$postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$postObject->setData($post);

$error = false;

if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']), 'NotEmpty')) {
    $error = true;
}
if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']), 'NotEmpty')) {
    $error = true;
} 
if (!\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
    $error = true;
}
if (\Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
    $error = true;
}
if ($error) {
    throw new \Exception();
}
```

Comment: This is the same as my question.